# How to open a exe with invisible window?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, properties

For example, I used this code in VBS to open a BAT in "mode invisible" (the window is invisible), but I wanted to try with a exe (chrome.exe) and it doesn't worked. It only works for BAT. I don't know how to programming in VBS :/. This is the code:

```
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run "chrome.exe",vbhide
```

Also, I tried use this code (that I founded in Google like other):

```
set args = WScript.Arguments
num = args.Count

if num = 0 then
WScript.Echo "Usage: [CScript | WScript] invis.vbs aScript.bat <some script arguments>"
WScript.Quit 1
end if

sargs = ""
if num > 1 then
sargs = " "
for k = 1 to num - 1
    anArg = args.Item(k)
    sargs = sargs & anArg & " "
next
end if

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """" & sargs, 0, False
```

But technically it's the same. I want to open a invisible window of a exe like chrome.exe (for example) and I don't know how to do it for a exe :/

---

Hi. Thanks for that. I used this code for IE and works:

```
Set IExp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
IExp.Visible = False
IExp.navigate "www.google.com.co"
```

But it doesn't work for Chrome, so I used this new code with Chrome like browser default:

```
Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.google.com.co"

set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run(iURL),vbhide
```

But it doesn't work for Chrome :/. I'm reading in Google that Chrome creates different process like the base and each tab of the browser. When Chrome starts it always there 2 or 3 process "chrome.exe" in task manager. So how do I open a invisible window of Chrome? :(

Answer (score 1):

The code does what you want it to do. However, if the executable/script you're running is just a launcher for some other executable/script the statement will hide only the launcher, not the launched program. To my knowledge it's not possible to influence the visibility of grandchild processes from VBScript.

*Demonstration:*

If you start Notepad from a VBScript like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe", 0, False
```

you'll get a hidden Notepad instance (you can see the process in the Task Manager's "Processes" tab).

Now create a batch script like this:

```
@echo off
start /wait notepad.exe
```

If you double-click that batch script you'll see two windows: one CMD window with the batch script, and a Notepad window.

However, if you run the batch script from a VBScript like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\path\to\your.cmd", 0, False
```

only the Notepad window becomes visible, because the batch process is hidden.